# Get value of parameter defined in callback javascript function

Tags: javascript

How can I retrive parameter "url" inside call back function?

Function declared in global scope:

```
var showPrompt = function(text, callBackFunc){
    $('#msg').html(text);
    $('#msgbtn').click( function(){callBackFunc();})
};
```

//calling function

```
$('li').click(function(){  // about 100 li el.
    var url = '/prod/' + $(this).data('id');
    showPrompt('Page will be redirected', function(url){
        window.location = url;
    })
})
```

Comment: Why are you down voting question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
showPrompt = function(text, callBackFunc, args){
    $('#msg').html(text);
    $('#msgbtn').click( function(){callBackFunc(args);})
};
//calling function

$('li').click(function(){  // about 100 li el.
    var url = '/prod/' + $(this).attr('id');
    showPrompt('Page will be redirected', function(args){
       alert(args.url);
    }, {'url':url})
})
```

Use this way (cleaner approach)

'- OR -

```
showPrompt = function(text, callBackFunc){
    $('#msg').html(text);
    $('#msgbtn').click( callBackFunc);
};
//calling function

$('li').click(function(){  // about 100 li el.
    var url = '/prod/' + $(this).attr('id');
    showPrompt('Page will be redirected', function(){
       alert(url);
    })
})
```

Comment: But still do you know how to reuse passed anonymous function url parameter?

Comment: I could not understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare `url` as a parameter to your function and you'll get the outer `url` that you want:

```
var url = ('error.html');
showPrompt('Page will be redirected', function() {
    window.location = url;
});
```

And you don't need the extra anonymous function inside `showPrompt`, just this is okay:

```
showPrompt = function(text, callBackFunc) {
    $('#msg').html(text);
    $('#msgbtn').click(callBackFunc);
};
```

Unless of course if you want to always call `callBackFunc` without any arguments. Attaching it as

```
.click(callBackFunc)
```

means that it will be called with the event as its argument.

Comment: Problem is, that i want to pass url parameter to showPrompt callback function, I don't want to declare it in global namespace.

Comment: @jmav: If the `showPrompt` call is inside another function then `url` will be a local variable for that function but will also be captured by the closure; so, no global needed.

Comment: true: but what if I'm using button, which is clicked much later by user. Code is not aware in which context is, so it doesn't know the url value.

Comment: @jmav: Where would the URL come from then? I think you need to provide a complete example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jmav: What's the problem with your `$('li').click()`? Works fine once you drop the `url` from the callback's parameter list: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vSayJ/

Answer (score 0):

```
showPrompt = function(text, callBackFunc) {
    var url = ('error.html');
    $('#msg').html(text);
    $('#msgbtn').click( function(){callBackFunc(url);})
};

//calling function
showPrompt('Page will be redirected', function(url){
    window.location = url;
})
```

you can do it like this. just declare url in the closure of function calling callBackFunc and then pass it as a parameter

Comment: As I sad, I want to pass url parameter to showPrompt callback function

Comment: His solution is passing a url paramete. I think you need to elaborate on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.